# Netbeans destroys hardlinks on save

Tags: netbeans, hardlink

I am using Netbeans 7.0.1 on a Linux system.

I have a file

`module/test.php`

and another one

`application/module/test.php`

Both `test.php` files are hardlinks of each other.

When I change `application/module/test.php` in Netbeans the `module/test.php` is not updated. But it should.

I think Netbeans deletes the test.php and creates a new one?

I believe in Netbeans 6 this did not happen.

How can I fix this? Is there any hidden option to get the old behavior?

Comment: Probably to get atomic saves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way for a text editor to update (save) a file is to create a new file in the same directory with a temporary name, write new contents there and then delete old file and rename the new one to its real name.

Rationale: If you're rewriting a file in place, any catastrophic failure (power loss, bad sector on disk, etc.) may leave this file corrupted or only partly written. Therefore any sane editor does not do in-place writes. I'm rather amazed that NetBeans did that in older versions.

Of course, this delete/rename method is not aware of your hard link, and searching a whole disk for other hard links to a file is not an option, so no editor does this.

I don't think you can get an old behavior, and even if you could, this is a pretty bad idea. If you cannot switch to soft links (which are not affected by this issue), I suppose you'll have to look for some other way to do what you're doing.

Comment: So I guess I will try to switch to soft-links.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Netbeans cannot be set to do a "one-stage" save, which is what you are asking for. What it does instead is a "two-stage" save.

An editor that can do that is [jEdit](http://www.jedit.org/), if that helps.
Here is what it says in the [Saving Files](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/saving.html) section of the jEdit manual :

> Two-Stage Save
>
> To prevent data loss in the unlikely case that jEdit should crash in
>   the middle of saving a file, files are first saved to a temporary file
>   named #filename#save#. If this operation is successful, the original
>   file is replaced with the temporary file.
>
> However, in some situations, this behavior is undesirable. For
>   example, on Unix this creates a new i-node so while jEdit retains file
>   permissions, the owner and group of the file are reset, and **if it is a hard link the link is broken**. The “two-stage save” feature can be
>   disabled in the General pane of the Utilities>Global Options dialog
>   box; see [the section called “The General Pane”](http://www.jedit.org/users-guide/global-opts.html#general-pane).